# Submitting modal form via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have a normal form for my question entity.

Within that form is a modal form which allows users to add additional tags for their question.

Here is an image of my modal form:

[image]

Here is my twig template for my modal form:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Tag</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="tagForm" id="tag-form" action="{{ path('addTag') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="tagName">Tag Name: </label>
                <input id="tagName" class="form-control" type="text"/>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input id="tag-form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Tag">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for viewing my modal form:

```
$('#addTag').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mymodal').modal();
    });
```

Script for my modal form submission:

```
$(function() {

    $('#tag-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('addTag') }}",
            data: $('form.tagForm').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response['response']);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

My problem is that everytime I click the add tag button, all the forms including the question form is also submitted.

What I really want is just to submit the modal form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your firing this on the submit event, which is why its....submitting? Maybe this would work better?

```
$(function() {

$('#tag-form-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('addTag') }}",
        data: $('form.tagForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response['response']);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro that worked. I also thought that was the problem but I don't how to implement the right code on jQuery since I'm just new to it.

Comment: Glad to help, if your looking to get more knowledge on jQuery I can recommend a series of video tutorials at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810

Comment: Thanks. I've already been watching MyBringback's tutorial on jQuery and it seems fine. I'll go try watching this one too.